# C# MySql for each column in mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql

So, in my database there is an accounts table and a characters table. And my goal is to Log all characters from the characters table where the accountId is the account id from the player. In my Database i have 2 characters, so i must get 2 logs in the Console.
My Question is, how can i make a a function which says, for each character in the characters table where the accountId is player account id, console log (if you know what i mean)
Here is the code:

```
try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection($"SERVER={Constants.DatabaseConfig.Host}; UID={Constants.DatabaseConfig.User}; PASSWORD={Constants.DatabaseConfig.Password}; DATABASE={Constants.DatabaseConfig.Database}"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE accountid=@accountid";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountid", player.accountId);

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow character in reader)
                            {
                                charId = reader.GetInt32("id"); 
                                firstName = reader.GetString("first_name"); 
                                lastName = reader.GetString("last_name"); 
                                dateOfBirth = reader.GetString("date_of_birth"); 
                                gender = reader.GetInt32("gender"); 
                                cash = reader.GetInt32("money_cash"); 
                                bank = reader.GetInt32("money_bank"); 
                                posX = reader.GetInt32("posX"); 
                                posY = reader.GetInt32("posY"); 
                                posZ = reader.GetInt32("posZ");
                                Console.WriteLine($"{firstName} {lastName}");
                                //player.Emit("Client:Charselector:Open_Insert", charId, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, gender, cash, bank, posX, posY, posZ);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e}");
        }
```

Everything works fine just i dont know how to make the foreach loop :(

Comment: You don't need a `foreach`, the `while` sorts that out. You also don't need `HasRows` check

Comment: omg thank you haha it worked. I come from NodeJS there you have to do a foreach so yea ty mate :)

Comment: do you maybe know how i can log how much characters i have? like if in my table i have 3 characters i want a console log which says "3".

Comment: Put in a counter variable, or maybe check `reader.RecordsAffected` not sure if that works on `SELECT`

Comment: RecordsAffected doesnt work and what do you mean with a counter variable? Do you mean like a variable and then always variableName++?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Normally you are anyway adding results to a list, so you would just check the count on that